# Python error: 'return' outside function

Tags: python, function, return

I'm having a problem with python and I cannot figure out why is it happening.

My code is the following:

```
def getServers(baseDN=''):
    from pyad import adquery
    q = adquery.ADQuery()
    q.execute_query(
        attributes=["distinguishedName", "description"], \
        where_clause="objectClass = 'Computer'", \
        base_dn=baseDN)
    #Lo que devuelve es un generator campeon :) Podes pasarlos con next o con un for.
    return [server['distinguishedName'].split(',')[0].strip('CN=') for server in q.get_results()] # Y aca lo parseo con un for
```

So basically, if I execute this code by executing a py file it works perfectly. However, if I try to use it on a console I get a "return outside function" error, and I cannot figure out how to solve it as I'm trying to debug my code by running pieces on the console :(

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You're not indenting your code properly in the console, and as such the text is not inside the function scope. This becomes a problem when you get to `return...` because `return` must be inside a function scope.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need line continuations here, python ignores line breaks inside parentheses.

Comment: Try removing the comment `##Lo que devuelve es u ... `

Comment: I agree that this is probably a simple indentation problem, but on the off chance it isn't, please provide a screen shot of your console after you enter your code and get the error.

Comment: Hi mates. Milind, the problem was the comment, I just moved that comment outside the function and now it is just working fine :)

Comment: This resolution is somehow unsatisfying to me. Comments are absolutely allowed inside functions, and should not cause any problems.

Comment: Read my comments on the below answer too. Things are being duplicated here. In my case it was the comment, and the console was the official console. As I wrote below, maybe the problem was somehow the localization of my text, I was copying it from pyCharm (The IDE I normally use, an old version in fact because I never updated it) and it was failing. Then I have removed the comment and it worked, but as I thought the same you do (I also know that comments are allowed inside functions...) I tried copying it to other IDE sometimes I use (Ninja IDE) and now it works (with the comment inside)

Answer (score 0):

The parser thinks that the function is over before the `return` statement, which means that there is probably some kind of problem with your indentation. Make sure that you have the same number of spaces/tabs before each line (or make sure you're not mixing spaces and tabs, spaces on some lines, tabs on others). It might also help to get rid of the commented line.

**Edit:** The fact that removing the comment fixed your problem would indicate that the console you are using is defective, since the syntax is correct.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this seems like speculation until we can get more information.

Comment: Hi bebop, somehow yes it was due to indentation, but not directly the indentation itself because the line was correctly indented, but the console was not understanding the indentation for some reason, I solved it by moving the comment outside the function, at least when I'm testing it on the console.

Comment: @Kevin I am still learning python, but this seemed straightforward enough. Can you think of something other than the two points that I suggested that could result in this error?

Comment: My own theories were: 1) the OP is writing something different in the console than what he wrote here, in which case the question should be closed as a typo instead of being answered; or 2) The OP is using a non-standard console or REPL, which has been poorly programmed and thus behaves incorrectly when provided with perfectly correct code. While "get rid of the commented line" did help the OP in this circumstance, it doesn't really get to the bottom of the issue, because comments inside functions _should_ work fine on the console.

Comment: If future users have this same problem and end up here, the conclusion they'll come away with will be "never ever use comments in functions" rather than "switch to a REPL that works" (or whatever the true problem is), which seems like a shame to me.

Comment: @Kevin Good point. Would be nice if Diego Marciano wrote which console he is using.

Comment: Hi guys, unfortunately something is not coherent with the comments from Kevin, because I'm using the console that cames with python. Specifically this one: 
>>> import sys
>>> print (sys.version)
2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: I had come to other conclusion anyways, and is that may the localization of the text  was somehow affecting my code, I was using pycharm so it should be fine, however if I copy it from there to the console it does not work, but I rewrote the code in other IDE (Ninja IDE) just to be sure, and if I copy it from there it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the comment before the return. The console for some reason was not understanding the continuation very well. As I was interested just in testing the code I simply removed the comment.

Comment: Which console are you using? Assuming that all the indentation is correct, it should be able to handle the comment correctly. There does not seem to be anything wrong with the syntax of the comment.

Comment: Hi Bebop, check the comments on the other answers, as comments are getting duplicated.